# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am using Eclipse and I have configured all the jars required for Spring Framework, it don't show any compilation error. But, when I run my main function(Test Class) it populates me this error. Am I missing something here? Please help me, could not find the actual solution to solve this problem.

```
 Feb 27, 2017 1:15:20 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/PropertyAccessor
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:481)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:14)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies are not required at compile time but just at runtime.

The missing class is contained in the [spring-expression](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-expression%22) jar. You can download it and add it to Eclipse too.

Comment: So i guess i need to create a Maven project where I have to mention above dependency in pom.xml

Comment: You can just add this as jar in Eclipse as you did with all your other jars.

Comment: I added above jar,  now it shows this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/SpringProperties
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.<clinit>(SpelParserConfiguration.java:36)
 at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.<init>(SpelExpressionParser.java:41)`

Comment: I have added com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1, org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A, org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A, org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A, org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A and spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE jars

Comment: All your Spring dependencies should use the same version. Otherwise there could be incompatibilities as you can see. You should go for 4.x because 3.0.1 is already over 7 years old.